# Responsive Iframe within Angular Material dialog content

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I would like for the iframe within the Angular Material dialog content to be:

1. maximum size of 560x315px
2. responsive size depending on the parent dialog container. if the container gets smaller than the maximum width
3. keep aspect ratio.

**SourceComponent.ts**:

```
openIFrameDialog(): void {
  this.dialog.open(IFrameDialogComponent);
}
```

**IFrameDialogComponent.html:**

```
<div mat-dialog-title class="close">
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="onClose()" tabindex="-1">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
<mat-dialog-content>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="[yt_video_url]" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

I also added this in **IFrameDialogComponent.scss:**

```
mat-dialog-content iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
```

but no luck, it expands on the entire screen not on the parent container

Any suggestions on how to achieve the above requests?

I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about use the max-width in your css( IFrameDialogComponent.scss) like this:
`max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;`

Comment: I also remove the fixed values in the iframe section